# Extra quote in <a ... class="question-hyperlink"">

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Many Stack Exchange pages contain anchors (`<a>` tags) with a `class` attribute set to `question-hyperlink`. There is an extra double quote after the class value. For example, on this very page:

`<a href="/questions/167180/extra-quote-in-a-class-question-hyperlink" class="question-hyperlink"">`

I first found it when parsing `/admin/review/community-eval-stats`:

`<a href="/questions/28041/whats-the-range-of-magnetos-powers" class="question-hyperlink"">`

Browsers don't seem to mind, but scrapers do. And there's stuff you can't get at with the API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm... fairly certain that this was fixed in a previous deploy.

At least, I don't see any other examples of this problem.